# Downloaded app won't open because it is from an unidentified developer

Tags: macos, applications

I have download photo express mac version on my MacBook Pro and it won't open it said can't opened because it is from an unidentified developer. But I'm using there mac download so what do I do so I can get it to work

Answer (score 3):

I would appear that for some reason the developer of Photo Express is not registered with Apple as an identified developer.

To get it to install you will need to go to System Preferences and change the default setting for application downloads...

System Prefs-> Security And Privacy -> and select Allow apps downloaded from Anywhere.

[image]

Remember to set the value back to Mac App Store and identified developers afterwards.

Comment: Or, more conveniently, right-click the downloaded .dmg or .pkg file and select Open. You will be asked to confirm that you want to open the unidentified installer, and then for your admin password if you agree. This way you don't have to remember to change anything back afterwards, which could leave you open to security breaches.